# GPL Alternative to Nomachine that is not FreeNX

Tags: linux, vnc

Anyone know something that is actively maintained? I'm currently using XRDP, but it is somewhat buggy, also I'd prefer to utilize non-corporate  driven standards, even though RDP is an open spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it meets all of your requirements, but I have really been liking X2Go.

http://wiki.x2go.org/

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, this is meant for embedded systems, as well as use over 3/4G Wireless networks and WiMax.

Answer (score -1):

**anydesk.com**
AnyDesk is really easier to install than TeamViewer and NoMachine.
It's fast!
My NoMachine (NX) and X2Go in Ubuntu Server 17.10 got really slow.

How to Install AnyDesk on Ubuntu & LinuxMint (TeamViewer Alternative):
 https://tecadmin.net/install-anydesk-ubuntu

Anydesk Automated Script for Ubuntu:
https://kkslinuxinfo.wordpress.com/2016/02/06/anydesk-automated-script-for-ubuntu

Comment: Not GPL though, so not an answer to the question as asked.